# How to Check if a User :key_down is Present in an Array/String

Tags: ruby, ruby2d

I am building a Hangman game in Ruby2d. I want to be able to tell if the key a user presses is present within an array of my chosen word.

I tried this, but nothing happens at all:

```
on :key_down do |event|
    if chosen_array.include? event.key  
        print "Correct!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Does `chosen_array`really contain this letter? Did you check output in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should show result in ruby2d window

```
require "ruby2d"

chosen_array = %w[a b c]

on :key_down do |event|
  clear

  result =
    if chosen_array.include?(event.key.downcase)
      "Correct!"
    else
      "Wrong"
    end

  Text.new(result)
end

show
```

If you press <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd>, result in window will be "Correct!", otherwise "Wrong!"